# javascript in android webview does not work in galaxy note 8/9

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, galaxy

I have an app that consists of a pure webview. I have been running this app for about six months and have had no problems so far. But about a month ago there was a problem.

Users of galaxy note 8 and 9 are experiencing inconvenience. My app will see the login screen for the first time. Here, users of galaxy notes 8 and 9 often do not work with javascript. The page refreshes and nothing happens. So they have to try the same login more than 10 times.

I also have a galaxy note 9, and I can see the same problem on my phone. However, I did not find any difference in configuration with other galaxies.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

The people who have the problem are android version 8.1.0,
chrome version is 66.0.3359.100 (most recent update).

Comment: IS the javascript running at all?  Did you try doing some simple print style debugging to test?

Comment: @GabeSechan I solved my problem, I have <a> tag into javascript submit code ( f.action = "", f.submit(); ), and when I click <a> tag, the javascript submit didnt work. But I realized that It works when I click 'Go' button in my keyboard.

Comment: @GabeSechan so I put <submit> tag instead of submit in javascript, It looks ok